# Oracle Application Framework - page run time delay

Tags: oaf

I am trying to run basic OAF pages from Oracle Jdeveloper. I have access to an Oracle EBS instance (both database and application server).

The page takes about 12 mins. to appear after I run a page from Jdeveloper.

The basic page which I am running is Hello World page.

Is it that this is an intentional delay created from EBS Instance side.

Please provide some suggestions.

Regards
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

When you run from JDeveloper it will take time as files gets compiled then get connected to server and all. If you can't wait, upload the compiled files directly to the main server/instance.

Answer (score 0):

The process to deploy a page from within JDeveloper from my experience takes about a minute and sometimes less. 12 minutes is way to much. Something that could cause some delays may be the connectivity between your JDevloper on your local system and the Database server on the central environment. Please check your database and runtime connection under "Default Project Properties". I run Jdeveloper 10.1.3.5